# get image source path using onclick event in next js

Tags: next.js

get the Image source when on click event of the image is fired in nextjs.

```
const imagesource = () =>{      
 render () {
    const imageClick = () => {
      console.log('Click',this.src);
    } 
    return (
       <div>
          <img src={require('/myfolder/myimage.png') onClick={this.imageClick()} />
       </div>
    );
 }
```

}
export default imagesource

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same for React.  You access the event object on click and then target the DOM element's attributes.  So it would look something like this:

```
const GetImagePath = () => {

  const getPath = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("resource path: ", e.target.src);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Click on the picture to get path</div>
      <img src="sample.jpg" alt="cute corgi" onClick={getPath} />
    </>
  );
};

export default GetImagePath;
```

Hopes this helps.